# ApachePOI and TestNG

Tags: apache-poi, testng

Issues:-

1. The dataprovider is directly going to exception block
2. How to return value of cell from data provider to `@Test` method in order to achieve parameterisation

   ```
   @DataProvider (name = "DP1")
   public void getData() throws IOException {
   try
   {
       FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\kk\\workspace\\K\\TestNG_Tutorial\\src\\Book1.xls"));
       System.out.println(file);
       //Get the workbook instance for XLS file 
       HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

       //Get first sheet from the workbook
       HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

       //Get iterator to all the rows in current sheet
       java.util.Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

       while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
           Row row = rowIterator.next();
           //System.out.println("Row is" +row);
           java.util.Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
           while(cellIterator.hasNext()){

               Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
               switch(cell.getCellType()) {
               case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                   System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t\t");
                   break;
               case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                   System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
                   break;
               case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                   System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                   break;
               }
           }
           System.out.println("");
       }
       file.close();
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   }

   @Test(dataProvider = "DP1")
   public void LoginTest() {
       driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("A");
   }
   ```

Comment: whats your exception?

Comment: I mean its not executing anything in the try block of the data provider method

Comment: The dataprovider annotation code is not executing at all. Is there a issue with the order? I have included dataprovider before Test annotation

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders). The dataprovider method must return either a 2-dimensional array or an Iterator<Object[]>.